# Error Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) in jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, ssh-keys

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 in which I've got ssh-agent setup.  Well, I don't need to type password when I do `git clone`.  I setup a Jenkins controller in that Ubuntu and used itself as an agent.  It's an ssh agent, and I'm using the user I regularly do `git clone` with to connect to the agent.  In one of Jenkins jobs, I just simply run bash, and do `git clone ....`, but I got the error saying

```bash
git clone git@gitlab.....
Cloning into '...'...
git@gitlab...: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Not sure why this is happening...

Comment: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone git@gitlab....` should provide more detail about what is and isn't happening in the session.